# Header-redirection within php-code won't work

Tags: php, http-headers, http-redirect

I want to redirect the user after emailing me.
The code runs unless I put something after the `email()`-method (like the `header()`-method).
Any hints?

```
function process()
{
    $msg = "Form Contents: \n\n";
    foreach($this->fields as $key => $field)
        $msg .= "$key :  $field \n";

    $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'thesubject';
    $from = $this->fields['email'];

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from\r\nReturn-Path: $from\r\n");

    header('Location: thanks.html');
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I used to get PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in D:\xampp\htdocs\process_form.php in the D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log

Comment: Does the email get send without any errors? What if you try with @mail(...) ?

Comment: $this->fields should be $field, right? $from = $field['email'];

Comment: yes, the email has been sent. But the redirection afterwards not.

Comment: rechecked again and, no...the email will not be sent if there is anything behind the mail()-method.

Answer (score 5):

When I run into similar problems, it's usually a missing semicolon at the end of a line or, as is the case here, missing brackets because`foreach` code block should be blocked off by {}. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your location should be absolute, not relative.

```
header("Location: /myPath/thanks.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

In my case, there were those quote signs. That did it.

Answer (score -1):

After header('location:  ....'); you should add an exit; Otherwise the script keeps running until its end.

```
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit;
```

Comment: You should add the exit anyway ;)